# How To Select A Range in an Iframe With "Start" and "End" in Firefox like "selectionStart" from inputs element

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, range, selection-api

for Internet Explorer, I have the current code to select a range in an iframe with desingMode setting to on:

```
    var Range = window.document.selection.createRange();
    var obj = { start: 3, end : 6}
    Range.collapse( true );
    Range.moveStart( 'character', obj.start );
    Range.moveEnd( 'character', obj.end - obj.start );
    Range.select();
```

Most useful if I want select only one piece of a string by only 2 parameters. Start and End ( for input elements exists the properties selectionStart and selectionEnd ).

When this code is executed, for example, on a string "Hello World", it highlight only the piece of string **llo Wo**, or something like that.
The problem is that Firefox Dom do not support the method moveStart or moveEnd, but only [range.setStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.setStart) and range.setEnd which request only a node and an offset as arguments.

So is possible to virtualizing the moveStart and the moveEnd methods in Firefox?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var iframeElement = ...; // the DOM element for the iframe;

var contentDoc = iframeElement.contentDocument;
var range = contentDoc.createRange();
range.setStart(contentDoc.body.firstChild, 3);
range.setEnd(contentDoc.body.firstChild, 6);
var selection = iframeElement.contentWindow.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

You need to call removeAllRanges() in Firefox or else you can end up with multiple selections.